# Outlook api $search not returning immutable id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I.am using microsoft graph to fetch mails. There are two ways to filter messages one is using $filter another one is using $search. My problem is I have listed mail accordingly and store thier id so i can download them. But if i move my mails for e.g. from draft to sent items i am not able to fetch that mail while download. For that in request header i pass Prefer as key and value idType=immutableId by doing this the itemid will not change even if i move them to another folder but this solution is not working if i am listing mail using $search,........ Any help is appreciable....

Comment: What output are you looking for exactly after applying $search or $filter?

Comment: Using $search and $filter i can retrieve mail which i am getting...but their id are not constant meaning that moving them to another folder will also change their id so storing that id is of no use....to overcome this Api provides facilty to pass Prefer as key and Idtype= immutableid while callimg Api by passing this the id  which it return is constant and moving mail to another folder will not change their id , but these method is working only while calling api $search and $filter is not returning immutable id

Comment: As of now this is not implemented with ODATA queries yet. However you can raise a uservoice for it in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Comment: Is there any way using which i can get immutable id or global id of mail while calling using $search like i am getting using $filter

Comment: I am not sure with outlook api but with MS Graph it cannot be done as of now. Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot search the immutable id of the messages using the $search, this is not implemented yet. However you can raise a uservoice for it in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).